# Best way to implement drag and drop upload Google Gears or HTML 5

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, google-gears

What would you recommend for supporting drag and drop upload - that is being able to drag a file icon from the desktop onto some "zone" on a web page and have it uploaded to the server. THe options are Google Gears,HTML 5 or anything else you can recommend. The criteria are:

should work on as many browsers as possible

should work into the future if possible (although this is less important as I can change the implementation if things change

the less effort required the better (in particular the less extra work required for each browser the better).

the less work the user has to do (i.e. download plugins, update browser version) the better

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at Plupload. It uses various plugins, gears, html5, flash, etc, to do the job for you. Drag and drop might be bit of problem for IE 7 and below.

http://www.plupload.com/documentation.php

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 drag and drop probably has the [widest acceptance](http://caniuse.com/#search=drag). But the main to keep in mind is that Google Gears is no longer supported and has no been dropped from Chrome in version 12 ( the current version )